# Php imap_search() FROM criteria using email address doesn't work in outlook

Tags: php, imap

I'm building a class that connects to an IMAP server. In my development environment I tried connecting to Gmail successfully, getting emails like this:

```
$emails = imap($this->connection, "FROM \"$source->email\" ");
```

The line above works as expected, it returns an array with the emails that matched the criteria, it works perfectly. e.g if $source->email = myemail@example.com, it will return only emails from that address.

However, when testing with the client's account in outlook I get an empty array using the same criteria. Even if the email address is static id doesn't work:

```
$emails = imap_search($this->connection, 'FROM "myemail@example.com"');
```

But doing the following does not return an empty array:

```
$emails = imap_search($this->connection, 'ALL');
```

The goal of the class is to extract some data from the emails, these emails are grouped by email addresses. Each group displays the content in a different pattern, so I have to distinguish all of them in order to instantiate the proper class that can extract the data from that group.

Any ideas on how to debug this ? or what might be the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is very interesting - at least  to me - as I'm struggling on it these days. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @DonCallisto, yeah... Inducing the client to go with google. I was lucky they  were open to this.

Comment: Ouch :) BTW I've found that solution is to change encoding of connection. Sadly I've found that outlook servers seems not to support utf-8 charset :\

Comment: So that worked out completely ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Please explain what you mean by 'change encoding of connection'.